# Android search for non ascii cyrillic characters

Tags: android, search, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm developing an app that is highly localized for my country, Macedonia. Over here we use Cyrillic alphabet. So the user needs to search for venues trough a search view.

How to search for Cyrillic names (i will send the query to a JSON service) if the user is using Latin IME keyboard?

I have two approaches in mind:

1. Map the inputted chars to it's corresponding cyrillic char and then send the translated query to that JSON service;
2. In the DB I can have field with the corresponding latin name of venue to I can search within that field;

Am I on the right track? Is there any more standard way of doing this?

Comment: The user changes its latin keyboard for a cyrillic one and you send the query in utf-8.